# doesNotMatch query in Parse not working

Tags: parse-platform

I have two objects in Parse. The first one is notification where I save every challenge my user get. The second one is UserChallenge where I store every challenge a user completes. I tried to do a combined query where I only get results of notifications for challenges the user didn't complete and I get nothing in return. I checked my data and I should get two objects back.

Does anyone can tell what I did wrong in the query?

```
var Completed = Parse.Object.extend("Picok_User_Challenge");
var completedQuery = new Parse.Query(Completed);
completedQuery.equalTo("picok_user_id",currentUser);

var Challenges = Parse.Object.extend("Picok_Notifications");
var challengesQuery = new Parse.Query(Challenges);
challengesQuery.include("new_challenge_id");
challengesQuery.equalTo("type", "CHALLENGE");
challengesQuery.equalTo("who_recived", currentUser);
challengesQuery.doesNotMatchKeyInQuery("new_challenge_id","picok_challenge_id",
    completedQuery);
challengesQuery.find({

    success: function(results) {
    console.log("createNotifiction success count: " + results.length);
    response.success("YAY");
},
error: function(object, error) 
{

    console.log(error);
    alert('Failed to get challenge not completed for: ' + request.params.user);
    response.error('Failed to get user challenges to complete for: ' + request.params.user);`
}
});
```

Comment: Have you tried running the queries individually?

Comment: yeah, I did the same query using the Android SDK and it works. I copied the values to make sure it is the same exact thing.